# Seeking source for localized Countries, Languages and Region names

Tags: localization, internationalization, multilingual

I seek a source for the world's main language names, country names, and territory names,  localised into a long list of languages.

Example of localised names of languages:

```
 EN EN English
 EN ES Inglés
 ES EN Spanish
 ES ES Español
```

Example of localised names of a certain country in south-west Europe:

```
 ES ES España
 ES FR Espagne
 ES EN Spain
```

Any idea where can I take/build that from?

Comment: I remove the sql tag, since this is not about the language SQL.

Comment: Further, I've removed the `mysql` tag and added `database`.

Comment: relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876103/i-have-a-list-of-country-codes-and-a-list-of-language-codes-how-do-i-map-from-c

Comment: Further, I've removed the "database" tag, as this has nothing whatsoever to do with databases. You may chose to *save* this data in a database, but that's irrelevant.

Comment: What I think you are looking for is a list of language names, country names, and territory names, localised into a long list of languages. I think you also may have an error in your first example of a country entry; it reads, `ES EN España` but I think you mean `ES ES España`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find the information you are looking for in the Unicode Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR) here: http://cldr.unicode.org/

Data is supplied in XML so you will need to import this into your database.

The CLDR publishes human-readable charts for [language names](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/by_type/code_lists.languages.html) and [territory (country, continent, etc.)](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/by_type/code_lists.territories.html) names. In each, there is a section for each language or territory, identified by a standardised code. Then the rows of each section give a localised name, and codes for the languages which use that localised name to refer to the language or territory.

The underlying CLDR data is in XML form. The language and territory names you seek are in directory, [repos/cldr/trunk/common/main/](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/main/), with an XML file for each language, containing the names for various languages and territories localised into that language.  For instance, the file [`es.xml`](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/main/es.xml) has the Spanish-language names for languages ("español", "inglés") and countries ("España").

Comment: Specifically http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/supplementalData.xml found off of http://unicode.org/cldr/charts/supplemental/territory_language_information.html

Comment: You are absolutely right, the CLDR is a great source for this data. I edited the question to add specific links to both human-readable charts and XML files of language and country names.

Answer (score 0):

For country names, you can use [geonames](http://www.geonames.org/AM/other-names-for-armenia.html), for example here is a list of alternate names for the [south west European country](http://www.geonames.org/ES/other-names-for-spain.html). Geonames has an [api and data dump](http://www.geonames.org/export/) that you can use in your programs.

For language names, [this list](http://www.verbix.com/languagenames/de.html) could be useful

Answer (score -1):

[HERE](http://www.odditysoftware.com/download/download.php?filename=countries-list.zip) is a database in multiple formats. 
Best of luck learning all those languages in their local slang.

Comment: The database is a list of countries with language codes and name in English only.