# Get Region Info in specific language

Tags: c#

I want to get the region info in specific language.
In my application user will be login with different language.
i.e English, Japanese, Chinese etc.

I have 2 digit country code from which I can get the Country Name using RegionInfo class, but I want the country name as par my application login language.

#### Is it possible to get country name in different language without using resource string.

e.g.

#### Case 1:

- Application language : English
- Country Code : JP
- Country Name : Japan [Expected output]

#### Case 2:

- Application language : Japaneese
- Country Code : JP
- Country Name : 日本 [Expected output]

Comment: Related: [Seeking source for localized Countries, Languages and Region names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163685/seeking-source-for-localized-countries-languages-and-region-names). The answer found there suggests using the Unicode Common Locale Data Repository ([CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/)) to build your own solution using the provided XMLs. The CLDR's page also mentions some libraries for other languages and a quick search revealed a .NET CLDR library called [onism](https://github.com/pgolebiowski/onism-cldr).

Comment: Could you possibly keep this information in a configuration file or perhaps a database?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RegionInfo ri = new RegionInfo("DE");
string nativeCountryName = ri.NativeName;
```

But I have 2 observations:

1. You will need to use the country, not the language. Which means that "JA" (language) will not work, but "JP" (country) will.
2. Japanese didn't quite work for me when I was testing on the Console. I guess it's due to lack of character support, but I'm not sure on this one.

Here is the code I used in the Console.

```
RegionInfo ri = new RegionInfo("JP");
Console.WriteLine("   Name:          {0}", ri.Name);
Console.WriteLine("   DisplayName:   {0}", ri.DisplayName);
Console.WriteLine("   NativeName:    {0}", ri.NativeName);
Console.WriteLine("   EnglishName:   {0}", ri.EnglishName);
```

And here is the result:
[image]

**EDIT**
Sorry, I've ignored the most important part of the question (get the country's name in the language the user selects). In that case, it's *not possible* and you will have to use a resource string.

Comment: But that will only return the native name of the country in the language of the country. If I understand the question correctly, you won't get the country name of Japan in, e.g., Chinese like that.

Comment: I have already tried with the above code.
result which I am getting is (NativeName = Deutschland)
If my application language is Japanese then Expected output is (ドイツ)

Comment: Sorry, missed that point. I've just edited the answer - not possible without storing the country localized names somewhere.